Overlay TIFF raster and "Shape" file a free library in C#?
Is there any free C# library to get the elevation data for the vertices of a 2D line feature Shape file form a raster tiff file?
The "Elevation" column in the attribute table of "ResultShape.shp" should have the elevation values of the vertices which are retrieved from the "MayRaster.tif".


GDAL has C# bindings and can do this. A single polyline will contain at least two vertices. How do you intend to put the two or more elevation values in a single attribute? A summary stat (min/max/mean) or do you want a 3D PolyLineZ?
